# How to assigning Datacontext as well as static value in a single Combobox

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to assign `datacontext` and static values in a single `Combobox`. I tried like this,

```
this.courseList.DataContext = ldc.Courses.OrderBy(x => x.CourseID);
this.courseList.Items.Add("All");
this.courseList.Items.Add("Others");
```

But, it shows `InvalidOperationException was Unhandeled` that `Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource.`

Then I tried like this,

```
this.courseList.Items.Add("All");       
foreach (var items in ldc.Courses.OrderBy(x => x.CourseID))
 {
   this.courseList.Items.Add(items);
 }
this.courseList.Items.Add("Others");
```

It works like this Image
[image]
Since I used an ItemTemplate in XAML design for this `Combobox` so it doesn't shows exactly in my way for this two value `All` and `Others`.

Here is the `ItemTemplate`

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="CourseTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CourseID}"/>
            <TextBlock Text=" : "/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CourseName}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

...
 <ComboBox Name="courseList" VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectionChanged="courseList_SelectionChanged" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CourseTemplate}"/>
```

I want it to view according to DataTemplate for database entries and simple strings `All` and `Others` for `All` and `Others` respectively like the image below.
[image]

Any suggestions. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says, you can only use ItemsSource or Items directly, not a mix of the two. Since you essentially have two different types of data that you want to show differently you can add them all to a single bound collection and then let the templates do the work of rendering them differently. Step 1 is to build the single collection:

```
this.courseList.ItemsSource = new object[] { "All" }.Concat(ldc.Courses.OrderBy(x => x.CourseID)).Concat(new[] { "Others" });
```

You now have 2 types of data in the collection: String and your object which I'll assume is Course. The strings will show up as you want without any extra work but you need to apply the DataTemplate only to the Course objects. The simplest way is just to replace your x:Key with a DataType:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type data:Course}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CourseID}"/>
        <TextBlock Text=" : "/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CourseName}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

where the data xmlns corresponds to your Course object's namespace.

Next just remove the ItemTemplate attribute from your ComboBox and you should get what you're looking for.

If you have other places in the same scope where you're also binding Course objects but want them to display differently you can either scope the DataType template more locally (i.e. a Grid.Resources) or use a DataTemplateSelector on your ComboBox.

Answer (score 1):

Since `ldc.Courses` is set as the `DataContext`, and you have `ItemsSource="{Binding}"` this means that the combobox is bound directly to your collection.  This creates a problem when you try to add strings as you did since now the collection has both strings and Course objects.

I think this will probably be the easiest solution to understand.  Starting with your second approach:

```
this.courseList.Items.Add("All");       
foreach (var items in ldc.Courses.OrderBy(x => x.CourseID))
 {
   this.courseList.Items.Add(items.CourseID.ToString() + " : " + items.CourseName);
 }
this.courseList.Items.Add("Others");
```

This will keep your combobox bound to a simple list of strings instead of objects, so as long as you don't need other information in the background this will be simpler to digest, if not try one of the other answers that mixes strings and objects into the same collection.  This would also mean you don't need to set the `DataContext`, the `ItemsSource`, or the `DataTemplate`, so erase all that.

If you want to keep the template to add a little more control, again you may want to look at some of the other answers.  Another alternative would be to create a parent class over your courses object that could also take the more general `ALL` and `OTHER` cases and create actual objects around them probably the most flexibility.  This way you wouldn't end with a collection of both strings and objects, which will cause you to have to create special code cases anytime you manipulate the collection.

Comment: 'System.Data.Linq.Table<LibraryAutomation.Course>' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Linq.Table<LibraryAutomation.Course>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

So, What is this assembly ?

Comment: @arefinsami ah I did not know the datatype of ldc from the context, I'll adjust my answer.

Comment: A linq to sql class
 LibraryDataContext ldc = new LibraryDataContext();

Comment: This approach removes the visualization of Course from the UI and loses flexibility. What if you need to make the CourseID bold or format it on two lines? With this approach you'd need to start over. Keeping the template allows you to make those visual changes in that same template.

Comment: @JohnBowen I agree, I just suggested it as a simpler alternative to your method as I'm sure having the itemssource contain a collection of varying types will be a landmine for the OP in the future.  I'll edit to emphasize this more, but you answer is definitely the more flexible one if he can figure out all the caveats.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by using ItemTemplate combined with converter.

Template:

```
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ComboBoxItemConverter}}" /> 
    </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Converter:

```
public class ComboBoxItemConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is Courses)
        {
            var course = value as Courses;
            return course.CourseID + " : " + course.CourseName;
        }
        else
        {
            return value.ToString();
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```